# Installing Two Operating Systems On Separate Drives

Tags: dual-boot

I removed from my laptop the SSD with Windows 10 installed. Then, I put in a different SSD and installed Ubuntu. Next, I put the SSD with Windows 10 back in the laptop alongside the SSD with Ubuntu. I turned on the laptop. What happens next?

-- Am I taken to BIOS and told to choose which OS to boot?

-- Does Windows take command and in doing so cause chaos: destroy the Ubuntu SSD?

-- Does the Ubuntu SSD even get recognised?

Let us say that the laptop system is a building managed by people independent of the Microsoft and Linux divisions (SSD's). And in this building there is a storage department. This department has many offices, of which, one is the SSD office. Is the SSD office going to show preferential/privileged treatment to Windows over Linux? For example:

Have the Windows 10 division (SSD) and the building's BIOS department (my laptop), or whoever, made an agreement that should any other non-Windows 10 division try to set up shop in the building the Windows 10 division be notified and consulted regarding any action to be taken?

-- Can the Ubuntu division (SSD) communicate with the building's staff without any third parties interfering/observing?

-- Is the building's BIOS department independent of external influence?

-- Hardware or software issue?

Memory (Division) > Storage (department) > SSD (office)  -- if so, what is UEFI/BIOS: division, department, or office?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Please go easy on the metaphors, it is not helping. Please see the site [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help) for what kind of questions are appropriate in this site and how to ask a question that is likely to give you an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, nothing catastrophic will happen (no need to alert homeland security)

Your bios will just remember the boot order and boot whichever has higher priority.

As for the os' "messing" with each other. Windows does not recognize the `ext4` fs natively so you won't be able to mount the drive.

As for Linux, unless you have a seciton in `/etc/fstab` that will mount the windows drive, or you explicitly mount it yourself, it should not be mounted therefore Ubuntu won't be able to see anything on that drive